# FlutteSecureStorage doesn't work on my project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I recently installed FlutterSecureStorage on my project, but when i try to run it , i get the error

```
C:\Users\pierre\source\repos\Erledigt\erledigt\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19: error: package com.it_nomads.fluttersecurestorage does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.it_nomads.fluttersecurestorage.FlutterSecureStoragePlugin());
```

please can someone help me solve this Problem ?

ps : this is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: erledigt
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.1
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: MontSerrat
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Did you upgrade Android minSdkVersion to >= 18 in your [project]/android/app/build.gradle ? Can you also post your pubspec.yaml please ?

Comment: yes i did upgrade the minSdkVersion to 18